# Flutter : type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Function'

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i have been using the custom_splash package and as the docs says if i want to Execute a function in background and based on the value from that function navigate to different screen i have to do the following :

```
import 'package:custom_splash/custom_splash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:omorfia/Admin/admin.dart';
import 'package:omorfia/presentation/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:omorfia/presentation/screens/login.dart';

import '../../application/user/providers/current_user.provider.dart';
import '../../homePage.dart';
import '../../screencontroller.dart';

Map<int ,Widget> controller =  {1:Login(),2:Home(),3:Admin()};

class SplashScreen extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final asyncUser = useProvider(currentUserProvider);
    print(
        'Rebuilding Splash with ${asyncUser.maybeWhen(data: (data) => data, orElse: () => 'nothing')}');
  //         Function duringSplash = () {
  //   print('Something background process');
  //   int a = 123 + 23;
  //   print(a);

  //   if (a > 100)
  //     return 1;
  //   else
  //     return 2;
  // };
        Function _duringSplash = (){
          int screenIndex ; 
          asyncUser.maybeWhen(
      data: (user) => user == null
          ?  screenIndex = 1
          : user.admin
              ?  screenIndex = 3
              : screenIndex = 2,
      orElse: () =>screenIndex = 1,
    );
    print("hello${screenIndex}");
    return screenIndex ;
        };

    return CustomSplash(
      backGroundColor: Colors.pink[100],
      home: MyApp(),
      duration: 5000,
      customFunction:_duringSplash() ,
      imagePath: "images/logo.png",
      animationEffect: "zoom-in",
      logoSize: 500,
      type: CustomSplashType.BackgroundProcess,
      outputAndHome: controller,
    );
  }
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/lamp-product.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: null /* add child content here */,
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

the function that is committed is the same function from docs so i did my own function that is returning an `int` but it won't work every time the function gets  executed this error pops up `type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Function'`
any idea what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line of code:

```dart
customFunction:_duringSplash() ,
```

to the following:

```dart
customFunction:_duringSplash,
```

What you were passing was the value returned by the function not the function.

Comment: do u got any idea why this error pops up in console ? 
`E/flutter (20521): #4      _CustomSplashState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:custom_splash/custom_splash.dart:117:25)`

Comment: I don't know. Which line is the 117th? Maybe, in that line, there are some problems.